# Import settings to IntelliJ via file system

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm preparing an IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3 rollout for about fifty software developers working with Windows PCs. To make life a little easier for them I want to provide some default settings fitting our company infrastructure and coding guidelines.

I've found I could export a file `settings.jar` but every developer would have to import it manually. That's not ideal.

An other way is to share settings via built-in plugin *settings repository*. But I couldn't get it to work properly with a git repository located at a network share.

Maybe I could overwrite files in directory `user.home/.IntelliJIdea2017.3/config/options` but installations are typically restricted to write to program files directories in Windows at our company.

Question is: Is there another way to import settings in IntelliJ via file system? I heard about dropping exported `settings.jar` to `plugins` directory in IntelliJ installation directory but that's not working either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no ready-made solution for this, however, you can write a small plugin that will import your settings file on startup, and deploy it to the `plugins` directory of your installation of IntelliJ IDEA.

You can find the implementation of settings import [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/configuration-store-impl/src/ImportSettingsAction.kt). The current implementation is not decoupled from the user interface, so you can't invoke it from your plugin, but basically the only important part for your usecase is this:

```
val filenameFilter = ImportSettingsFilenameFilter(getRelativeNamesToExtract(dialog.exportableComponents))
StartupActionScriptManager.addActionCommands(listOf(
  StartupActionScriptManager.UnzipCommand(tempFile, File(configPath), filenameFilter),
  StartupActionScriptManager.DeleteCommand(tempFile)))
```

You can simply perform the same operation in an `ApplicationComponent` of your own plugin.